# Cliente TCP/IP se congela al enviar datos a Servidor

Tags: java, socket, tcpip

Es un servidor "echo" donde quiero que cuando se conecten dos clientes envíen un String al servidor, este último conteste y el cliente imprima lo leído.

El caso es que uno de ellos se me queda sin responder, uso Threads en el servidor por cada cliente que se conecta.

Cliente :

```
public class Client {
    protected Socket sk;
    public DataOutputStream out;
    public DataInputStream in;
    public Boolean exit=false;

    public Client(String addr, int port) {
        try {
            sk = new Socket(addr, port);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cli Socket"+e);
        }
    }

    public void readLines(){

        String line;
        Mess m=null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            in= new DataInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
            System.out.print(">>");
            while((line=sc.nextLine()).equals("quit")!= true){
                out.writeUTF(line);
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cli readlnes:"+e);
            sc.close();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (sc != null) {
                    sc.close();
                }
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (sk != null) {
                    sk.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Conexión finalizada");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    public ServerSocket sk;
    protected int port;
    public DataInputStream in;
    public DataOutputStream out;

    public Server(int port){
        this.port=port;
        try {
            sk= new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server"+e); 
        }
    }

    public void serve(){
        while(true){
            try {

                System.out.println("Waiting....");
                final Socket csk = sk.accept();
                new Thread(){
                    public void run() { serveClient(csk); }
                }.start();
                System.out.println("Accept connection.."+csk.getLocalAddress()+" "+csk.getPort());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Srv serve"+e);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void serveClient(Socket sk){        
        String result=null;
        Mess m;
        boolean exit = false;
        try {
            out=new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
            in= new DataInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
            while(!exit){           
                    result=in.readUTF();
                    out.writeUTF(result);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Servecli "+e);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: amigo, podrías mejorar un poco mas la redacción y usar palabras mas técnicas y/o formales, eso demuestra tu profesionalismo, recuerda agregar  las etiquetas correspondientes para que puedas encontrar mas personas dispuestas a ayudarte a resolver tu problema. saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el servidor acepta la petición de cliente en el hilo principal y realiza el trabajo de comunicación en un hilo adicional. La aceptación de los clientes también debe estar en el hilo adicional, no en el hilo principal.

El código debe lucir así:

```
try {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Waiting....");
            final Socket csk = sk.accept();
            System.out.println(String.format("Accept connection. %s %s",
                csk.getLocalAddress(), csk.getPort()));
            serveClient(csk);
        }
    }.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Srv serve"+e);
}
```

Pero esto ahora genera un problema puesto que el código está dentro de un ciclo `while(true)` que correrá eternamente, de manera que tendrás un ciclo que creará hilos eternamente. Lo mejor para estos casos es no crear los hilos manualmente y delegar este trabajo a un pool de threads. `ExecutorService` es una interfaz que te prove dicha funcionalidad y así evitas crear esto manualmente:

```
static final int MAXIMO_HILOS_DEFECTO = 10;

int numeroHilos = MAXIMO_HILOS_DEFECTO;

//...
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numeroHilos);
while (true) { //<-- esto debería ser una variable, no true
               //lo dejo en true para no complicar más el ejemplo
    executor.submit( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Waiting....");
            final Socket csk = sk.accept();
            System.out.println(String.format("Accept connection. %s %s",
                csk.getLocalAddress(), csk.getPort()));
            serveClient(csk);
        }
    });
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Desde Java 8, puedes reducir el código utilizando lambdas:

```
executor.submit(() -> {
    System.out.println("Waiting....");
    final Socket csk = sk.accept();
    System.out.println(String.format("Accept connection. %s %s",
        csk.getLocalAddress(), csk.getPort()));
    serveClient(csk);
});
```